# npm ERR! cb<> never called! - browserSync

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, browser-sync

I'm new to grunt and am hitting a wall with BrowserSync. Whether I try to install it globally or for a particular folder

```
npm install -g grunt-browser-sync
```

Or

```
npm install grunt-browser-sync --save-dev
```

I get the same error: `npm ERR! cb<> never called!` I've tried `npm cache clear` and deleting the node_modules folder and runing `npm install` again but nothing seems to help.

Watch, Compass, and Uglify are all working. I just can't get browserSync to install successfully.

Here is a copy/paste of commands I just entered and the results.

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\testing>npm install grunt-browser-sync --save-dev
npm WARN package.json testing@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json testing@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\xampp\htdocs\testing\node_modules\socket.io\node_mo
dules\engine.io requires debug@'1.0.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\xampp\htdocs\testing\node_modules\socket.io\node_mo
dules\debug,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.7.4
grunt-browser-sync@1.5.3 node_modules\grunt-browser-sync
└── browser-sync@1.9.0 (emitter-steward@0.0.1, easy-extender@2.2.0, opt-merger@1
.1.0, commander@2.6.0, opn@1.0.1, object-path@0.8.1, minimist@1.1.0, eazy-logger
@2.1.0, ua-parser-js@0.7.3, browser-sync-client@1.0.1, lodash@2.4.1, dev-ip@0.1.
7, portscanner-plus@0.2.0, connect@3.3.4, serve-index@1.6.0, tfunk@3.0.0, serve-
static@1.8.0, glob-watcher@0.0.7, localtunnel@1.5.0, resp-modifier@1.0.1, foxy@7
.1.0)

D:\xampp\htdocs\testing>grunt browserSync
Running "browserSync:bsFiles" (browserSync) task
Warning: Cannot find module 'base64id' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

D:\xampp\htdocs\testing>
```

Please advise.

---

following sskips suggestion below I got the following error:

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\testing>npm install base64id
npm WARN package.json testing@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json testing@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\xampp\htdocs\testing\node_modules\socket.io\node_mo
dules\engine.io requires debug@'1.0.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\xampp\htdocs\testing\node_modules\socket.io\node_mo
dules\debug,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.7.4
base64id@0.1.0 node_modules\base64id

D:\xampp\htdocs\testing>
```

Answer (score 0):

you lose something.

install base64id as below, then try again

> npm install base64id

Comment: @CreateSean  that means installed success, please try what you asked,  it works now?

Comment: Now I get a warning cannot find moudle 'ws' use --force to continue

Comment: @CreateSean run "npm install ws", if u got 'con't find error', install it

Comment: When I do that I get a Failed at the ws@0.6.5 install script error.